# Nodejs showing 413 Payload Too Large on nginx server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, http-status-code-413

I'm running this code on my Amazon AWS server without load balancer. It's a simple server I setup. I'm trying to run a code that crawls for data, written in nodejs. Currently, it's showing the error shown below when I upload a lot of data to crawl:

```
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 413 Payload Too Large
```

After many of the suggestions I read here on StackOverflow, I added `client_max_body_size 500M;` on http, server, location and restarted the server but it doesn't have any effect on it.

Here's the nginx.conf file:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    client_max_body_size 500M;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  example.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html/crawler;
        client_max_body_size 500M;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            #try_files $uri /index.html;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200/;
            client_max_body_size 500M;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to consider those points :

1. What's the size of your POST request? It might be bigger than 500MB, therefor you could raise the limit even further, technically, you'll only need to put it on the server (Even tho chunking the post data would be way better than raising the limit)
2. Are you using Express? Maybe did you put up some limits on the request size with Express.

Kind regards

Comment: Thanks for spotting out second thing, that was my issue